# Solving an integral with three product terms, none of which reduce to constants after differentiation

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to solve this definite integral with three product terms. I tried the three term version of integrating by parts, but none of the terms containing the variable reduce to constants after differentiation so I am out of ideas

$\int_{0}^{X} e^{i/x}e^{jx} x^{k} dx = 1$

Where $i$, $j$, and $k$ are constants greater than zero.

General strategies for this type of equation would be appreciated as well as potential solutions. My intuition suggests that there's a way to use the limits to my advantage, but I can't find it.